# Why is "Hide Others" keyboard shortcut missing on macOS Chrome?

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome

I've noticed within the last week that the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> keyboard shortcut to `Menubar / Chrome / Hide Others` has disappeared from the latest version of Google Chrome (70.0.3538.77) on macOS (10.13.6) High Sierra.

[image: Chrome menu]

Pressing the shortcut does nothing (it hasn't been remapped to a new command) in Chrome. The shortcut still appears and works in all other Apple and third-party apps.

[image: Finder menu]

Running Disk Util First Aid and rebooting macOS doesn't help. I can workaround by adding a custom shortcut to System Prefs for Chrome or for all apps, by why did this happen, is there a better, more direct fix?

Comment: same issue for me, I'm disappointed. Looks like an update of Chrome which removes the shortcut

Comment: I also just noticed i have the same issue!

Comment: I filed a Chrome bug so hopefully we can get an answer or get this fixed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=913365

Comment: It is being tracked here now: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=892480 Apparently there is a fix, but it hasn't gone mainstream yet.

Comment: I have a slightly different variant of this question that is still unresolved: Google Docs (and slides, and sheets) eats `cmd-option-h` such that Hide Others does not from within those apps. It's been driving me nuts and I've found no solution... any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug that appeared in Chrome 70.0.3502.0](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=892480). It was fixed in Chrome 72, which was released a few days ago.

If the keyboard shortcut is still missing from your copy of Chrome, you might need to quit and then reopen it for the new version to become active.

To confirm you're on the new version, open Chrome and then either go to `chrome://settings/help` or select *About Google Chrome* from the Chrome menu.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem and followed the instructions in [How to Create Custom Keyboard Shortcuts in Mac OS](http://osxdaily.com/2017/08/08/create-custom-keyboard-shortcut-mac/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Read the last part of the question, it states, "I can workaround by adding a custom shortcut to System Prefs for Chrome or for all apps, by why did this happen, is there a better, more direct fix?", so he already knows how to assign a keyboard shortcut but that's not what he's asking... he asking "why did this happen, is there a better, more direct fix?"

Comment: Right sorry guess I didn't read that part so buzzing of to do something else. File a bug on chrome?